# Hibernate inject Criterion into Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a code with Hibernate restrictions like:

```
Criterion budgetTypeRestriction;
budgetTypeRestriction = Restrictions.between("code", "01", "03");
```

And how I can inject `Criterion` into `Query`?:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("from Regions");
```

It is easy for me collect `Criterion` logic, and then pass it to DAO, which is implemented throw `Query` and parameter binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Query (HQL) you don't use Criterion.

Instead you use HQL expressions in where clause which are similar to SQL:

`Query query = 
    session.createQuery("from Regions r where r.code between '01 and '03'");`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you expect the below

```
List<Regions> regionsList=sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Regions.class)
                          .add(Restrictions.between("code", "01", "03")).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Criteria API instead of a query. You can add sql restrictions to a criteria with Restrictions.sqlRestriction() if you need that.